# Defining system of Equations

Tags: nonlinear, system

I am not able to define a system of `n` equations having `n` variables `x1`, `x2`, `x3`,..., `xn` as a function of the form `f[x1,x2,x3,..., xn]`. Please suggest Mmathematica code for following system of equations

[image: System of 20 non linear equations]

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Actually, I do-not have to solve the equation directly. I am using different iterative methods as part of research. I need to perform certain operation on these system of equations. So the issue I am facing is how to define the equation as a function. Like we use f[x_] for equation with 1 variable and f[x_,y_] for equation with 2 variable. Then for n variables (like 20 in the above problem), how to define the function?

Comment: Please use the *edit* function and add the actual question from your comment to the post, such that it would be more clear.

Answer (score 7):

What about this?

```
n = 20;
Table[x[i] - Cos[2 x[i] - Sum[x[j], {j, 1, n}]] == 0, {i, 1, n}]
```

You will have a hard time solving this symbolically. But you can try to use `FindRoot` (which will apply Newton's method) to the system with random starting position. Sometimes, it will converge, sometimes not:

```
sol = FindRoot[
  eq,
  Transpose[{
    Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}],
    RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}]
    }],
  MaxIterations -> 1000
  ]
check = Max[Abs[eq[[All, 1]] /. sol]] < 10^-12
```

> {x[1] -> 0.828213, x[2] -> -0.539622, x[3] -> 0.828213,   x[4] ->
>   0.828213, x[5] -> -0.539622, x[6] -> 0.828213,   x[7] -> -0.539622, x[8] -> 0.828213, x[9] -> -0.539622,   x[10] -> 0.828213, x[11] ->
>   -0.539622, x[12] -> -0.996153,   x[13] -> -0.539622, x[14] -> 0.828213, x[15] -> -0.539622,   x[16] -> 0.828213, x[17] -> -0.539622, x[18] -> -0.539622,   x[19] -> 0.828213, x[20] -> -0.539622}
>
> True

To write the left-hand side as a function, just use

```
f = X \[Function] X - Cos[X - Total[X]];
```

Whenever you call `f` with a vector, you will get a vector of the same length:

```
n = 4;
XX = Table[Indexed[X, i], {i, 1, n}];
f[XX]
f[{1., 2., 3., 4.}]
```

> {-Cos[Indexed[X, {2}] + Indexed[X, {3}] + Indexed[X, {4}]] + 
>     Indexed[X, {1}], -Cos[
>       Indexed[X, {1}] + Indexed[X, {3}] + Indexed[X, {4}]] + 
>     Indexed[X, {2}], -Cos[
>       Indexed[X, {1}] + Indexed[X, {2}] + Indexed[X, {4}]] + 
>     Indexed[X, {3}], -Cos[
>       Indexed[X, {1}] + Indexed[X, {2}] + Indexed[X, {3}]] + 
>     Indexed[X, {4}]}
>
> {1.91113, 2.1455, 2.2461, 3.03983}

(Definitely, this looks much nicer in a notebook.)

Should you ever need the first and second derivatives (not unlikely, right?), you can define them as follows (alas, only for vectors of length fixed by `n`):

```
Df = X \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[XX], {XX, 1}]];
DDf = X \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[XX], {XX, 2}]];
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the results obtained by Henrik Schumacher NMinimize
gives a solution without  starting values

```
n = 20;
eq = Table[x[i] - Cos[2 x[i] - Sum[x[j], {j, 1, n}]] , {i, 1, n}];
NMinimize[  eq.eq, Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}] ]
(*{5.57364*10^-31, {x[1] -> 0.0826685, x[2] -> 0.0826685,x[3] -> 0.0826685, x[4] -> 0.0826685, x[5] -> 0.0826685,x[6] -> 0.0826685, x[7] -> 0.0826685, x[8] -> 0.0826685,x[9] -> 0.0826685, x[10] -> 0.0826685, x[11] -> 0.0826685, 
x[12] -> 0.0826685, x[13] -> 0.0826685, x[14] -> 0.0826685,x[15] -> 0.0826685, x[16] -> 0.0826685, x[17] -> 0.0826685,x[18] -> 0.0826685, x[19] -> 0.0826685, x[20] -> 0.0826685}}*)
```

In this solution all `x[i]` are equal!?!

```
maxerror=eq /. sol[[2]] // Abs // Max
(*2.77556*10^-16*)
```

The solution seems to be something like a minimal solution of the equations:

```
xi = Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}] ;
NMinimize[{xi.xi, eqgln == 0}, xi](* minimalsolution*)
(*{0.136682, {x[1] -> 0.0826685, x[2] -> 0.0826685, x[3] -> 0.0826685,x[4] -> 0.0826685, x[5] -> 0.0826685, x[6] -> 0.0826685,x[7] -> 0.0826685, x[8] -> 0.0826685, x[9] -> 0.0826685, 
x[10] -> 0.0826685, x[11] -> 0.0826685, x[12] -> 0.0826685,x[13] -> 0.0826685, x[14] -> 0.0826685, x[15] -> 0.0826685,x[16] -> 0.0826685, x[17] -> 0.0826685, x[18] -> 0.0826685,x[19] -> 0.0826685, x[20] -> 0.0826685}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Symmetric solutions ($x_i = x$):

```
NSolve[x == Cos[-18 x], x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -0.897978}, {x -> -0.840894}, {x -> -0.576715}, {x -> -0.463081}, {x -> -0.247883}, {x -> -0.0924075}, {x -> 
>      0.0826685}, {x -> 0.277416}, {x -> 0.412698}, {x -> 
>      0.650189}, {x -> 0.739184}}

```
Plot[{x, Cos[-18 x]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# - Cos[-18 #] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to define the function:

```
n=3;
f[x_] := Table[x[[i]] - Cos[2 x[[i]] - Total[x]], {i, n}]
```

With n=3, f[{1.0, 2, 3}] takes the value {1.65364, 2.41615, 2.}, and of course any n will work.